# Vue interpolation does not work in the text obtained by API

Tags: vue.js, interpolation, linear-interpolation

Get text by API, in text have a entities in {{}}, like a:

`Some text {{rules}} other text`

Have in data values:

`rules: "some text"`

but this values dont interpolated, displays:

`Some text {{rules}} other text`

thanks for answer

Comment: Please share your code. The parts of the code you included in your question should or should not be working - depending on other parts. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and rephrase your question.

Comment: I have:

template:

<div>{{someText}}</div>

have data:
  data() {
            return {
                someText: "some text {{ myValue }} some text",
                myValue: "300",
            }
        },

How display data from myValue in template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the comment above:

> I have: template: {{someText}} have data: data() { return {
> someText: "some text {{ myValue }} some text", myValue: "300", } },
> How display data from myValue in template?

You don't do interpolation like that in Vue. Double braces (`{{}}`) are for the **template** part, not the scripts.

Look at this snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      someText: "some text {{ myValue }} some text",
      myValue: "300"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    parsedSomeText() {
      let ret = ''
      if (/(\w+)(?= }})/g.test(this.someText)) {
        let key = String(this.someText).match(/(\w+)(?= }})/g)[0]
        if (Object.keys(this.$data).includes(key)) {
          ret = this.someText.replace(/{{ (\w+) }}/g, this.$data[key])
        }
      }
      return ret
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  myValue: {{myValue}}<br /> someText: {{someText}}<br />parsedSomeText: {{parsedSomeText}}
</div>
```

I created a small parser in `parsedSomeText()` **computed property**, that very crudely replaces the double braces in the `someText` data property and returns the modified string, so to get it working in the **data** property.

I advise you to look over the data you receive, and think of another solution - or utilize some rock-solid parsing technique to use it in production.

If you cannot avoid getting data in such a way, then you should look into dynamic (run-time) compilation (like: https://alligator.io/vuejs/v-runtime-template/) and render functions (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html). With these, your Vue app becomes more versatile but more complex.